# A problem with dplyr (applying which.min to a list of dataframes)

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

There is this issue with using which() and which.min in map() and lapply where I only get one number as my output, however, there are multiple vector values that satisfy the condition.
**DATA**

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
foo <- dplyr::tibble(a=c("a","b",NA),b=c("a","b","c"),colC=c("a",NA,"c"))
bar <- dplyr::tibble(a=c("a","b",NA),b=c("a","b","c"),colC=c("a",NA,"c"))
all_tibbles <- c("foo","bar")
mget(all_tibbles)
```

> ```
> $foo
> # A tibble: 3 x 3
>   a     b     colC 
>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
> 1 a     a     a    
> 2 b     b     NA   
> 3 NA    c     c    
>
> $bar
> # A tibble: 3 x 3
>   a     b     colC 
>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
> 1 a     a     a    
> 2 b     b     NA   
> 3 NA    c     c
> ```

```
mget(all_tibbles) %>%
  map(~ rowSums(!is.na(.x)))
```

> ```
> $foo
> [1] 3 2 2
>
> $bar
> [1] 3 2 2
> ```

```
mget(all_tibbles) %>% map(~ rowSums(!is.na(.x))) %>% map(~ which.min(.x))
lapply(mget(all_tibbles) %>% map(~ rowSums(!is.na(.x)) ),which.min)
```

> ```
> $foo
> [1] 2
>
> $bar
> [1] 2
> ```

As you see there is definitely more than column two. I was expecting which.min to output 2 3

Comment: From `?which.min` : "Determines the location, i.e., index of the **(first)** minimum or maximum of a numeric (or logical) vector."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we want both entries, use `==` as `which.min` returns only the first occurence of the match

```
mget(all_tibbles) %>% 
     map(~ .x %>%
             mutate(new = rowSums(!is.na(.))) %>%
             filter(new == min(new)) %>% 
             select(-new))
```